# SQL convert string to time format

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, time

I want to convert string time `'141312110'`  to this:  '`14:13:12.110'`

Actually, I have `bigint` column has data like `'20151110182425000'` I want to convert them to `datetime` format like

```
'10-11-2015 18:24:25.000'
```

I divided them to date and time to get date part used this :

```
Convert(varchar(10), convert(datetime, '20151110'),105)

Result : '10-11-2015'
```

And  needed to get time part like that.

Comment: What DBMS are you using (SQL Server, MySQL, Oracle, something else)?  And what version of the DBMS are you using? The answer will be very different depending on that.

Comment: Well it's the same as getting the date part, you convert to varchar and parse the string.   What part are you stuck on?

Comment: Added `sql-server` tag based on the usage of `convert()` and `datetime`

Comment: @tab alleman time part not getting with the same way cause convertting datetime, time format not mach.

Comment: @siyual using MSSQL 2008

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can turn your original string into the format "YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS.SSS'.  This should be recognized as a datetime, regardless of internationalization settings.

And you can do this with a bunch of `stuff()`s:

```
select cast(stuff(stuff(stuff(stuff(stuff(cast(val as varchar(255), 15, 0, '.'
                                         ), 13, 0, ':'
                                   ), 11, 0, ':'
                             ), 9, 0, 'T'
                       ), 7, 0, '-'
                 ), 5, 0, '-'
             as datetime)
```

Comment: Yes i also did this but i need dd-mm-YYYY hh:mm:ss, and can't do that using the stuff or i did not discover the way of doing this with stuff